# WSO2 : Database polling tutorial timestamp is not updating

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I followed following sample with one different i used MS SQL database.
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/11/scheduled-database-polling-with-wso2-data-services-server/

I am observing that polling is working as expected but timestamp (datetime column in sql is not getting updated)

Here is my DSS XML

```
 <data enableBatchRequests="true" name="PollingService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/eventing_sample" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="Default">
      <property name="driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://geoshieldsp3\sqlexpress;databaseName=RahulTest</property>
      <property name="username">sa</property>
      <property name="password">CSSL#2014</property>
   </config>
   <query id="pollingQuery" output-event-trigger="pollingTrigger" useConfig="Default">
      <sql>select x.[Call Number], x.Priority, x.Call_Type, x.DispatchDate,y.total from CADFeeds as x left join &#xd;(select *,count([Call Number]) over() as total from CADFeeds ) as y on x.[Call Number]=y.[Call Number]   &#xd;where x.DispatchDate &gt; (select TIMESTAMP from Timestamp where id=1)</sql>
      <result element="Calls" rowName="call">
         <element column="Call Number" name="CallNumber" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="Priority" name="Priority" xsdType="float"/>
         <element column="Call_Type" name="Call_Type" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="DispatchDate" name="DispatchDate" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="total" name="count" xsdType="integer"/>
      </result>
   </query>
   <query id="UpdateTimeStamp" useConfig="Default">
      <sql>update dbo.Timestamp set timestamp = GETDATE() where ID=1</sql>
      <param name="timestamp" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <event-trigger id="pollingTrigger">
      <expression>//*[local-name()='count' and namespace-uri()='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/eventing_sample']&gt;0</expression>
      <target-topic>polling_Topic</target-topic>
      <subscriptions>
         <subscription>http://localhost:8280/services/PollingProxy</subscription>
      </subscriptions>
   </event-trigger>
   <operation name="PollingOperation">
      <call-query href="pollingQuery"/>
   </operation>
   <operation name="UpdateTimeStamp">
      <call-query href="UpdateTimeStamp">
         <with-param name="timestamp" query-param="timestamp"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

Here is the DB schema for timestamp table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timestamp](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[timestamp] [datetime] NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

I do not see anything in the log or command prompt related to timestamp update.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch between the operation and the query.

For the below SQL, query param is not needed as there are no arguments supplied. 
Please try the following.

```
<operation name="UpdateTimeStamp">
      <call-query href="UpdateTimeStamp">
      </call-query>
</operation>

<query id="UpdateTimeStamp" useConfig="Default">
      <sql>update dbo.Timestamp set timestamp = GETDATE() where ID=1</sql>
</query>
```

Comment: I made changes you suggested and updated following                 
 `<event-trigger id="pollingTrigger">
      <expression>//*[local-name()='count' and namespace-uri()='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/eventing_sample']&gt;0</expression>
      <target-topic>polling_Topic</target-topic>
      <subscriptions>
         <subscription>http://CSSLLAPTOP-168:8280/services/PollingService</subscription>
      </subscriptions>
   </event-trigger>` now getting an error The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found

Comment: @Rahul can you please post the proxy service xml that is deployed in your ESB?

Comment: I did not create proxy service earlier, i created it now and here is how it look `<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="PollingProxy"
  startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://cssllaptop-168:9764/services/pollingService/"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>`

Comment: Use the below proxy just to log the payload from dss service. Hope the DSS service works fine with the previous changes. see the payload from dss in our esb logs, GOOD. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="PollingProxy"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>`

Comment: I replaced the xml in source view now i am getting an error. I am missing something but unable to figure out what?  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.ws.internal.notify.WSEventDispatcher} - Unable to send message org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199) org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)

Comment: in DSS ?? or ESB? are both in same system or different? also modify the insequence as following  `<inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>`

Comment: Made the changes. Still see the same error. Yes ESB and DSS are on same server. I tried changing offset to 1 in cardbon.xml file but after that change wso2 does not work.